# my camera doesn't follow the player when i say start the game

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to make a simple hyper casual. I couldn't understand what's wrong with my codes.

My code:

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{

  public Transform Target;
  public Vector3   offset;

  void LateUptade()
  {
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, Target.position + offset, Time.deltaTime * 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide your source code as text, not as image.

Comment: Do you just want a simple view onto the player without a delay effect? Have you considered to place the cam into the player's game object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Things to note in your code.

1. Its LateUpdate and not LateUptade.
2. In lerp If the third input is 1 the camera will instantly jump to target+offset and if you want the camera to move slowly from its position to target+offse then you need to increase the value of the third input from 0 to 1 every frame.

You can also use Cinemachine to make camera follow player. Check out this [Camera follow player tutorial](https://vionixstudio.com/2019/12/02/camera-follow-script-in-unity/) for different ways to make the camera follow player.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my typo. I was not aware

Answer (score -1):

Do **not** put `Time.deltaTime` in `Lerp`. The lazy solution is to simply write a constant that is between 0 and 1.

Additionally there is a typo in the function name. It should be `LateUpdate` and not `LateUptade`.

```csharp
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, Target.position + offset, 0.3f);
```

Comment: thanks but still not following

Comment: Time.deltatime is a tiny weeny near 0 number. So it will never move beyond a tiny weeny bit past the original position each time.   It will get there. Eons later

Comment: I missed your typo in the function name. @Vionix identified it correctly (and has been compensated with an upvote)